# Use URL, tabs[0].url, obtained from chrome.tabs.query() outside the callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

```js
chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    lastFocusedWindow: true
}, function (tabs) {
    // and use that tab to fill in out title and url
    var tab = tabs[0];
    console.log(tab.url);
    alert(tab.url);
});
```

This code shows me the URL in the `alert()` window, but I need to store this URL in a variable so I can store it or display it as I need.

Comment: var url = tab.url ? Be more explicit with the problem you are having

Comment: i need it outside the function it's ok if i need  can create a var inside the function var url = tab.url ; but i need to use it outside

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Also related:[Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron).